# Mandatory profile on Terminal server fails to load. Userenv.log debug

Tags: terminal-server, user-profile

We're having a lot of corrupted profiles lately on our profile share. At the moment I have no clue why, but I decided to switch to one mandatory profile since the users can all use the same and there is no need to have seperate profiles for each user.

Here's what I did. I logged into the Terminal server with a new user and configured some stuff (imported certificates and a few files). Then I logged out. Later as admin I copied the profile to another server and renamed it to bsilo. I made sure the user hive settings were adjusted. Everyone had access to the hive. I shared the bsilo folder with full access for everyone. I set the NTFS permissions to read, read & execute, list folder contents for domain users. I also renamed NTUSER.DAT to NTUSER.MAN.

Now I set a env variable %manprofile% on the Terminal server that points to \server\bsilo\ntuser.man

I set the env var as terminal services profile path for a test user. When I log in I as the user get the following output

The system cannot find the path specified.   Can somebody point me in the right direction. Thanks

`USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:39:724 InitializePolicyProcessing: Initialised Machine Mutex/Events
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:39:724 InitializePolicyProcessing: Initialised User Mutex/Events
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:39:724 LibMain: Process Name:  \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\winlogon.exe
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 LoadUserProfile: Yes, we can impersonate the user. Running as self
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 =========================================================
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 LoadUserProfile: Entering, hToken = <0x340>, lpProfileInfo = 0x6e5d8
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 LoadUserProfile: lpProfileInfo->dwFlags = <0x0>
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 LoadUserProfile: lpProfileInfo->lpUserName = 
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 LoadUserProfile: lpProfileInfo->lpProfilePath = <\server\bsilo\ntuser.man>
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 LoadUserProfile: lpProfileInfo->lpDefaultPath = <\BDPINF5\netlogon\Default User>
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 LoadUserProfile: NULL server name
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 LoadUserProfile: no thread token found, impersonating self.
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 GetInterface: Returning rpc binding handle
USERENV(218.2f94) 15:52:48:005 IProfileSecurityCallBack: client authenticated.
USERENV(218.2f94) 15:52:48:005 DropClientContext: Got client token 000009B4, sid = S-1-5-18
USERENV(218.2f94) 15:52:48:005 MIDL_user_allocate enter
USERENV(218.2f94) 15:52:48:005 DropClientContext: load profile object successfully made
USERENV(218.2f94) 15:52:48:005 DropClientContext: Returning 0
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 LoadUserProfile: Calling DropClientToken (as self) succeeded
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 CProfileDialog::Initialize : Cookie generated 
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:48:005 CProfileDialog::Initialize : Endpoint generated 
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:005 IProfileSecurityCallBack: client authenticated.
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 LoadUserProfileI: RPC end point IProfileDialog_9D36D6DD48F0578A2A41B23D7A982E63
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 In LoadUserProfileP
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 LoadUserProfile: Running as client, sid = S-1-5-18
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 =========================================================
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 LoadUserProfile: Entering, hToken = <0x98c>, lpProfileInfo = 0x9c940
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 LoadUserProfile: lpProfileInfo->dwFlags = <0x0>
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 LoadUserProfile: lpProfileInfo->lpUserName = 
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 LoadUserProfile: lpProfileInfo->lpProfilePath = <\server\bsilo\ntuser.man>
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 LoadUserProfile: lpProfileInfo->lpDefaultPath = <\BDPINF5\netlogon\Default User>
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 LoadUserProfile: NULL server name
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 LoadUserProfile: User sid: S-1-5-21-807756564-1922302612-1565739477-22627
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 CSyncManager::EnterLock 
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-807756564-1922302612-1565739477-22627 added in bucket 11
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:020 LoadUserProfile: Wait succeeded. In critical section.
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:864 GetOldSidString:  Failed to open profile profile guid key with error 2
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:864 GetProfileSid: No Guid -> Sid Mapping available
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:864 TestIfUserProfileLoaded:  return with error 2.
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:864 GetOldSidString:  Failed to open profile profile guid key with error 2
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:864 GetProfileSid: No Guid -> Sid Mapping available
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:864 LoadUserProfile: Expanded profile path is \server\bsilo\ntuser.man
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:880 ParseProfilePath: Entering, lpProfilePath = <\server\bsilo\ntuser.man>
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:880 CheckXForestLogon: checking x-forest logon, user handle = 2444
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:880 CheckXForestLogon: policy set to disable XForest check
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:48:880 ParseProfilePath: Mandatory profile (.man extension)
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:239 AbleToBypassCSC: Try to bypass CSC
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:239 AbleToBypassCSC: tried NPAddConnection3ForCSCAgent. Error 2109
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:239 AbleToBypassCSC: Share \server\bsilo mapped to drive E. Returned Path E:\ntuser.man
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:239 ParseProfilePath: CSC bypassed. Profile path E:\ntuser.man
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:255 ParseProfilePath: Tick Count = 0
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:255 ParseProfilePath: GetFileAttributes found something with attributes <0x2022>
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:255 ParseProfilePath: Found a file
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:255 ReportError: Impersonating user.
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:255 ReportError: Logging Error 

DETAIL - The system cannot find the path specified. 


  


USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:255 GetInterface: Returning rpc binding handle
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:255 ReportError: RPC End point IProfileDialog_9D36D6DD48F0578A2A41B23D7A982E63
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:49:255 ReportError: waiting on rpc async event
USERENV(1774.2398) 15:52:49:255 ErrorDialogEx: Calling DialogBoxParam
USERENV(1774.2398) 15:52:49:270 ErrorDlgProc:: DialogBoxParam
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:177 RpcAsyncCompleteCall finished, status = 0
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:177 ReleaseInterface: Releasing rpc binding handle
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:177 LoadUserProfile: ParseProfilePath returned FALSE
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:177 CancelCSCBypassedConnection: Cancelling connection of E:
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:177 CancelCSCBypassedConnection: Connection deleted.
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:177 CSyncManager::LeaveLock 
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:192 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:192 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-807756564-1922302612-1565739477-22627 deleted
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:192 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:192 LoadUserProfile: 003 About Reverted back to user <00000000>
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:192 LoadUserProfile: Leaving with a value of 0.
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:192 =========================================================
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:192 LoadUserProfileI: LoadUserProfileP failed with 3
USERENV(218.1f38) 15:52:52:192 LoadUserProfileI: returning 3
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:52:192 LoadUserProfile: Running as self
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:52:192 LoadUserProfile: Calling LoadUserProfileI failed. err = 3
USERENV(218.200c) 15:52:52:192 IProfileSecurityCallBack: client authenticated.
USERENV(218.200c) 15:52:52:192 ReleaseClientContext: Releasing context
USERENV(218.200c) 15:52:52:192 ReleaseClientContext_s: Releasing context
USERENV(218.200c) 15:52:52:192 MIDL_user_free enter
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:52:192 ReleaseInterface: Releasing rpc binding handle
USERENV(1774.d18) 15:52:52:192 LoadUserProfile: Returning FALSE. Error = 3`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. follow this article to set up your default user profile. This is the correct method. No hammer needed. This will create a custom Default user profile which you can then copy to all of your TS servers or to the Netlogon share in the domain and will become the template for all roaming profiles.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780839(WS.10).aspx

2. Follow this article to set up your roaming profile share. No hammer needed.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737633(WS.10).aspx

3. Disable Offline file caching on the roaming profile share to eliminate the profile corruption problem.